# MVVM stopping count down timer in the view holder

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview

My app uses MVVM pattern and want to get this done right. Have a count down timer (CountDownTimer) in RecyclerViewer view holder. I want the timer to be canceled when the app goes to foreground. There is onBindViewHolder() but no such thing like onUnBindViewHolder().

onPause() can only set adapter items to null beyond that it doesn't have control on individual view holders (fair enough).

Any suggestions on how to "update" the recycler view item (without any change in model) when app goes to background?

Comment: You should take a look at `LifeCycleObserver` from Android Architecture Components. It can notify you about `onPause` in your `ViewModel` and there you can cancel the timer.